# How to set default value on date picker ( sysdate + :pageitem) (Not working) Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, datepicker, oracle-apex, sysdate

I have 2 date picker on Oracle Apex page ; `P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE` and `P7_REQARRIVALDATE`.

`P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE` need to 'tomorrow' value = `sysdate +1`

`P7_REQARRIVALDATE` need to '10 days later' `value = sysdate + 10`

I adjust their default with this ; `to_char(sysdate + 1,'DD-MM-YYYY')` and `to_char(sysdate + 10,'DD-MM-YYYY')` **was working** BUT they don't want me to do statically so I need to fix it.

I have hidden page items ;
`P7_493DEPDATE` (value is 1 ) and `P7_493ARRDATE` (value is 10) ( the values coming from sql query) (varchar)

SO this is not working or the changes that I can imagine not working so I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what .

For example;

`to_char(sysdate + :P7_493DEPDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')` (not working)

`to_char(sysdate + $v('P7_493DEPDATE'),'DD-MM-YYYY')`  (not working)

at this point I don't know if I need to create **DA** or should I try to do it **with default value**. Thanks

(I checked the similar questions couldn't help myself)

---

**UPDATE 22 November 2023**

First of all thank you for your answer, both your answers seems usefull. I found to how to fix it before I get any answer so I couldn't write anything here . I fixed the problem by creating Dinamic action and set value . Thank you for your time again! I appreciated that! (I will not delete the question so other people can get help from it too.)

[image: setvalue-photo]

[image: inside-setvalue]

Answer (score 1):

I presume that `P7_493DEPDATE`'s sequence is **higher** than `P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE`:

[image]

---

For `P7_493DEPDATE` item, source is query that returns single value:

```
SELECT 10 FROM DUAL
```

For `P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE` date picker item, source is expression:

```
to_char(sysdate + :P7_493DEPDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE - +1d

P7_REQARRIVALDATE - +10d
```

if not static then **create a dynamic action** on change event
on **P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE** to update **P7_REQARRIVALDATE**.

```
event type- set value.
set type plsql expression -

to_date(P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY') +10
item to submit P7_REQDEPARTUREDATE
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).